# Update previous fields from addFields(); Discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

I don't know how to ask this but I'm trying to make a suggestion command that stacks reasons when a  staff runs the command to deny or accept the application, this uses code in 2 different files, here's the suggestion.js file code:

https://pastebin.com/raw/4svJAuNW

Heres the index.js code:

https://pastebin.com/raw/PNMfnMdz

It would be appreciated if I could be helped out with this since it's a nice feature to have.
Thanks

What it looks like right now:
[click here for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmchJ.png)

What I'm trying to accomplish [click here for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCAkE.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can't update fields, what you can do, is update the description

```js
const fields = `User: test\nUser: test2`
embed.setDescription(`**Denied**\n${fields}`)
```